# Angular appends component to the page nad wont remove old when route changes

Tags: angular, chromium

I'm having this strange behavior where when i click on a button what should take me to another route the component what should be displayed on that route gets added to the page but the old component what the new one should replace is never removed.

Application itself is using Angular 10

What makes it strange is that

- It only happens intermittenly, i refresh the page and some times this glitch happens sometimes not
- Problem exists in google chrome and edge but not in firefox
- There is no errors in console
- When i resize the window it snaps out of this strange faulty state and renders the correct component. Same happens when i open dev tools. And sometimes even helps when i do random click anywhere (doesnt have to be button or link).

Any idea where to look or what could be causing this anomaly?

**EDIT:**
Here's a recording of the page html to show whats happening when clicking on a button. The new component gets added and old component is not removed until i do a mouse click.
[image]

Comment: Are you using any page transition animations? That's the only time I've seen anything like that. Maybe update Angular version

Comment: I do have the angular's BrowserAnimationModule and it is used for a carousell component. No page transition animations tho.

Comment: can you share the code of this repo or reproduce it in a new project and share it?

Comment: from my experience this happens when you have a code that run outside of the ngZone, but I can't say what is running outside without seeing the code

Comment: what library are you using to make the "side-bar"? I feel that the problem can be there

Comment: Eliseo, this was just one simple place where i recorded this. Same thing happens when any other navigation button what causes angular to render a new component.

Comment: Since there is no code to reproduce you can only guess it yourself. I could advise checking following: 1) Enable routing tracing - you might find something interesting there, 2) Update your packages to the latest patch versions, 3) Ensure you don't have a RouteReuseStrategy, 4) Try commenting out components used on the page that can't detach perhaps one of them is doing something on destroy which breaks the flow, 5) Try incognito mode, 6) Try another browser - could be some extensions interfering

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause to this is that the component is unable to destroy itself at the time of the route change and then until the change detection is triggered again (ex: clicking something, resizing the app) it remains stuck in the dom. Perhaps the `onDestroy` or the animations block it from being destroyed in time.

Injecting the `ChangeDetectorRef` and calling `detectChanges()` in the `onInit` might help to solve the problem but not the root issue.

Without a minimum code example there is little more I could advise.

Comment: Im not able to replicate the problem in minimum code example. Only place i can see this happening is on live production website.

Comment: @hs2d can you replicate it if you do the prod build of the replication?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is happening due to the "timing" problem of routing in Angular.
Basically it sounds like the root cause of the problem is due to rendering of the new component out of Angular Zone.

I suggest you should try 'NgZone' module to perform the navigation.
Below is the code snippet for your reference :

```
import {Injectable, Injector, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class SampleComponet{

  constructor(private injector: Injector, private router: Router) { }

  performNavigation(): void {
    const ngZone = this.injector.get(NgZone);
    ngZone.run(() => {
       this.router.navigate(['/new-component'], { skipLocationChange: true });
    });
  }
}
```

Hopefully this will help you to solve the problem. Let me know by providing your feedback here so that it will be helpful for others in future.